# assert list contains elements of given class in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, assertions

I have a chain manager that contains some handlers. I would like to check if it has handlers of specific classes by default. How to do that?

```
def "contains few updaters on default"(){
    when:
        def manager = new UpdateManager();
    then:
        manager.getUpdaters().size() == 2;
        //how to check that the list contains elements of classes 
        //OneThingUpdater and OtherThingUpdater
}
```

edit:
I've improved the code from Answer, to defend against two elements of the same class, so it is like this now:

```
def "contains few updaters on default"(){
    setup:
        def expectedUpdaters = [OneThingUpdater, OtherThingUpdater]
    when:
        def manager = new UpdateManager();

    then:
        def list = manager.getUpdaters()
        list.size() == 2;
        list.every {
            it.class in expectedUpdaters
            expectedUpdaters.remove(it.class)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def "contains few updaters on default"(){
    when:
    def manager = new UpdateManager()

    then:
    def list = manager.getUpdaters()
    list.size() == 2
    list*.getClass().every { it in [OneThingUpdater, OtherThingUpdater] }

    // or, just this
    // Assuming the classes do not implement Map interface
    // getClass() can be replaced with class
    list*.class == [OneThingUpdater, OtherThingUpdater]
}
```

Comment: it will pass if we have two OneThingUpdaters, but thanks for inspiration, I've changed it to have expectedUpdaters list in "when", and on every found element I remove it from expected list.